# Как вывести заказы подробно в личном кабинете пользователя в 1С Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте!

Нужно вывести список заказов и заказы подробно в личном кабинете пользователя.
Есть компонент sale.personal.order, с помощью которого, как я понимаю, можно это сделать.

В папке компонента sale.personal.order находятся 3 файла: 
- list.php (список заказов)
- detail.php (заказы подробно)
- cancel.php (отмена заказа),
с помощью которых подключаются нужные компоненты.

Компонент sale.personal.order вызываю в папке personal/history-orders/index.php
Но что указывать в путях? (код ниже)

```
"SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
        "list" => "", // что указывать здесь?
        "detail" => "order_detail.php?ID=#ID#", // что указывать здесь?
        "cancel" => "order_cancel.php?ID=#ID#", // что указывать здесь?
    ),
```

Не совсем ясно, как открыть страницу с заказами подробно, например.
Если указать путь  "detail" => "order_detail.php?ID=#ID#", нужно создать страницу order_detail.php в папке personal/history-orders/index.php, где происходит вызов компонента?

Как происходит вызов этих компонентов? Как битрикс определяет куда лезть и какую страницу использовать?
При вызове компонента ведь не указываются пути к этим 3м файлам (list.php, detail.php, cancel.php):

Answer (score 1):

Можно не использовать компонент, получаете все заказы пользователя по его ID далее по ID заказа можно получить его данные.

```
//Получаем заказы текущего пользователя
    static function getOrdersByUser(){
        if (CModule::IncludeModule('sale'))
        {
             global $USER;
             $result = array();
             $arFilter = Array(
               "USER_ID" => $USER->GetID(),
               "DATE_CANCELED" => ""
         );

        $db_sales = CSaleOrder::GetList(array("DATE_INSERT" => "ASC"), $arFilter);
        while ($ar_sales = $db_sales->Fetch())
        {
           $result[] = $ar_sales;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
//Получаем свойства заказа по ID
    static function GetPropsOfOrder($order_id){
        $arrResult = array();
        $obBasket = \Bitrix\Sale\Basket::getList(array('filter' => array('ORDER_ID' => $order_id)));
        while($bItem = $obBasket->Fetch()){
            $arrResult[] = $bItem;
        }
        return $arrResult;
    }
```

как то так